# Is there a Python news site that's the near equivalent of RubyFlow?

Tags: python

I really like the format and type of links from [RubyFlow](http://rubyflow.com) for Ruby related topics. Is there an equivalent for Python that's active? There is a [PythonFlow](http://pythonflow.com), but I think it's pretty much dead.

I don't really like http://planet.python.org/ because there's lots of non-Python stuff on there and there's very little summarization of posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.reddit.com/r/Python is my favorite source for Python news.

Comment: so far this is closest to what I'm looking for - if there's nothing else in a few hours; I'll just mark this as the answer; already added that sub-reddit a while back hehe

Comment: I read it pretty much every day at work. Along with http://www.reddit.com/r/Programming for more general ideas

Answer (score 2):

Possibly http://www.planetpython.org/ or http://planet.python.org/.

Comment: sorry I added that last sentence too late

Answer (score 2):

http://planetpython.org/ (the unofficial planet) is generally better than http://planet.python.org/ (the official one) - I think the maintainers of the unofficial one are a bit more active in trimming feeds and maybe more careful about subscribing to Python category feeds if available (they certainly subscribe to the python tag on my blog rather than the whole feed).

Comment: didn't realize http://planetpython.org/ was dif from http://planet.python.org/ - though it looks like the major dif is that it removes all the non-python posts from http://planet.python.org; is there something that summarizes posts it besides reddit?